# how to Use multiple AND Operations in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

suppose i have 4 parameters eg distance , head count , travellers and country score. what i want to  do is if distance<=5 && head count <=20 && travellers <=30 && country score <=1 , then we should get value "VERY LOW".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with SWITCH function.
https://dax.guide/switch/

```
SomeMeasure = SWITCH( TRUE(),
Table[distance]<=5 && Table[head count] <=20 && Table[travellers] <=30 && Table[country score] <=1 , "VERY LOW",
Table[distance <= 10 && Table[Head count] <= 40 && Table[[travellers] <= 60 && Table[country score] <=2 , "LOW",
"NORMAL"
)
```